# having hard time understanding one issue in consumer producer problem

Tags: c, operating-system, semaphore

I am having really hard time understanding one issue in consumer producer problem for example in the below image  which is about the simple structure of consumer:

[image]

My big problem is that in wait(mutex) and signal(mutex) the parameter mutex is the same for both so it makes sense that signal(mutex) wake up wait(mutex) process if it is blocked but in wait(full) and signal(empty) they pass different parameters so how signal(empty) can wake up wait(full)??????(it is noteworthy that we assume both full and empty are of type semaphore)

here is some more information that may help:

[image: semaphore]
[image]

[image]

also the code for producer is:

[image]

Comment: And where is the code for the producer?

Comment: It looks like you got it from a book. What is the book telling about it? It seems, empty and full are different semaphores/mutexes, one doesn't wake up if you signal the other...

Comment: I put all the other information that I saw in book

Comment: And full and empty are different semaphore but you can see that book claim that it works in this way!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mutex semaphore handles avoidance of mutual access to some shared resource, the full and empty semaphores handle when producer and when consumer is allowed to run. It all depends on the setup of the semaphores but basically full should be set up to block on the first wait of the consumer, empty should be available on first wait in consumer.

The producer will then handle data and post on the full semaphore, which in turn will unblock the consumer task. Consumer will block on the next empty wait until producer posts the empty semaphore and so on until infinity or program end.

Answer (score 1):

Any producer/consumer solution uses a buffer.  Practical buffer implementations need to deal with the buffer having a finite size.  It thus needs to solve *two* synchronization problems.  One is the obvious one, the consumer needs to be blocked when the buffer is empty and woken up again when an item enters the buffer.  The less obvious one is that producer needs to be blocked when the buffer is filled to capacity, unblocked when a consumer removes an item.

Two very distinct blocking operations that affect different pieces of code.  It thus requires two semaphores.

Answer (score 1):

This concept is purely based on synchronization. Note two important things:

**1. About *full* and *empty*:**
Producer can not produce if the buffer is full and the consumer can not consume if the   buffer is empty. So, semaphore *full* and *empty* are used only to check this requirement. Please, refer to your text, the initial value for empty is n(size of buffer) and initial value of full is 0(no item for consumer yet). 
Step I. Producer has *wait(empty)* to check if the buffer has space(only then produce).
Step II. It has *signal(full)* to confirm that it has successfully produced one more item. Consumer can consume it now.
Step III. Consumer has *wait(full)* to check if it can consume something or not as whenever producer will produce an item, he will confirm(through Step II).
Step IV. Consumer has *signal(empty)* to confirm that it has consumed one time and so, the buffer space is free.(again Step I).

**2.About *mutex***: The mutex variable is only to ensure that at one time,only one process accesses the buffer. That's why Producer and Consumer both have *wait(mutex)* and *signal(mutex)*. Whenever any process(be it producer or consumer) accesses buffer, it acquires *mutex* and when it leaves buffer, it releases *mutex*.